# How to handle null values in geolocation (point) object in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, null, geospatial, point

I am currently working with a mongodb containing a collection of companies with the following structure:

```
{
    "_id": "52cdef7c4bab8bd675297d8e",
    "name": "Facebook",
    "offices": [{
        "description": "Headquarters",
        "address1": "1601 Willow Road",
        "address2": "",
        "zip_code": "94025",
        "city": "Menlo Park",
        "state_code": "CA",
        "country_code": "USA",
        "latitude": 37.41605,
        "longitude": -122.151801,
        "location": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-122.151801, 37.41605]
        }
    }, {
        "description": "Europe HQ",
        "address1": "",
        "address2": "",
        "zip_code": "",
        "city": "Dublin",
        "state_code": null,
        "country_code": "IRL",
        "latitude": 53.344104,
        "longitude": -6.267494,
        "location": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-6.267494, 53.344104]
        }
    }, {
        "description": "New York",
        "address1": "340 Madison Ave",
        "address2": "",
        "zip_code": "10017",
        "city": "New York",
        "state_code": "NY",
        "country_code": "USA",
        "latitude": null,
        "longitude": null,
        "location": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [null, null]
        }
    }]
}
```

I would like to create a geospatial index on the location field:

```
db.startups.createIndex( { "offices.location" : "2dsphere" } )
```

However, some of the offices longitude and latitude are null values so that index creation fails with `Point must only contain numeric elements`.

My question is how I should and/or could handle this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just drop the entire location for the offending element:

```
"location": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [null, null]
}
```